# Is there a key to trigger the home button on an external iPad keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut to trigger pressing the <kbd>home</kbd> button on an iPad when using it with an apple (bluetooth) keyboard?

Comment: The iPad dock has it in the position of the escape key. Try hitting that.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer appears to be no. The [Apple iPad Keyboard Dock](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/reviews/entry/apple-ipad-keyboard-dock/) for the first generation iPad had a physical home button on the keyboard, but successor products compatible with the iPad 2, including the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard have [been unable to replicate this feature](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3034205?start=0&tstart=0). Not the answer you're hoping for, I'm sure, but I'm afraid it's the answer, for now. Of course, Apple could change all this with a software update.