# Apple wireless keyboard + iPad 4: can I map a key to the home button?

Tags: ipad

I use the Apple wireless keyboard A1314 (newer model, using two AA batteries) with my iPad 4th (or is it 3.5th generator? whatever is the newest) generation. Is there a way to map one of the buttons to the home key? Is it possible to do this with a jailbroken iPad, if not a jail-unbroken iPad?

[An earlier answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26146/is-there-a-key-to-trigger-the-home-button-on-an-external-ipad-keyboard) says it isn't possible, but refers to iPad 2, so I don't know if anything has changed in the 1.5+ years.

This is more than a minor annoyance with the otherwise great Incase Origami stand, because the home button is physically blocked with the iPad in portrait mode.

Comment: I don't think it is possible still. If you don't mind using the right-click on your mouse as the home button, this might work: http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/10/how-to-use-a-mouse-on-the-ipad.html (NOTE: It's a jailbreak tweak.)

Comment: Oh cool! I'll have to get a bluetooth mouse and try this.

Comment: what iOS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but for anyone else coming across it, the answer is Command-H is the shortcut to display the home screen.

FYI

- Command H displays the home screen
- Command-Tab shortcut displays the task switcher
- Command-Space toggles the search bar

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iPhone perspective with the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard. 
My keyboard is a little older, and for whatever reason CMD + TAB doesn’t bring up the App Switcher nor switch between apps on the iPhone. 
CMD + H = Home Screen. 
CMD + S = Search.
CMD + TAB does nothing.
Upward pointing triangle which on the Mac used to eject a CD toggles the on-screen keyboard.
ƒn key toggles the emoji keyboard.
CNTL+SHIFT will toggle off any secondary keyboard language you may have activated to your preferred keyboard language.

Note: there are two ƒkeys, or FUNCTION+[ƒkey]. set up for multi-app + switcher (above the 3 and 4 keys, respectively), but neither seems to work on the iPhone. I haven’t tried using them in combination with a MacBookPro or iMac.

Also: Holding down the CMD key within any app with bring up a list of available CMD + shortcuts.